# Not able to set values of Global Variables inside RazorPay response

Tags: angular, typescript, razorpay

I am trying to use the custom checkout of RazorPay.

**Expected Behaviour**
*netBankingKeys* is flooded with an array of banks
*fetched* is changed from false to true

**What's happening**
the first setTimeout functions prints undefined
the second setTimeout functions says that the value is flase
the third setTimeout functions works as expected

I have tried to increase the timeout value from 4 to 20 sec but still *netBankingKeys* remains undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.razorpay.once('ready', function (response) {

      //Converts the object to array sets the global variable with the value
      this.netbankingKeys = Object.keys(response.methods['netbanking']).map((key) => [{ name: response.methods['netbanking'][key], key: key }]);

      //sets local storage with the stringify value
      localStorage.setItem("banks", JSON.stringify(this.netbankingKeys));

      //flag to say data was fetched initially false
      this.fetched = true
    })

    //prints undefined
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.netbankingKeys) }, 4000)
    //prints false
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.fetched) }, 4000)

    //works fine
    setTimeout(() => { console.log(localStorage.getItem("banks")) }, 4000)


  }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. So you have to wait until 'ready' is triggered. Did you debug your application?

Comment: I am waiting for it. The fact that is bugging me is

setTimeout(() => { console.log(localStorage.getItem("banks")) }, 4000)

this works fine

but

setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.netbankingKeys) }, 4000)

this gives me undefined

Comment: Why don't you console.log right inside your subscription?

Comment: the console log is just to show the state of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

**service to get access to native browser window**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window() : any {
 // return the global native browser window object
  return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {
  get nativeWindow() : any {
    return _window();
  }
}
```

**code for component**

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowRef } from "./core/services/winref.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  fetched: Boolean = false;
  rzp: any;
  rzpObservable: Observable<any>;
  netbankingkeys: any[];
  title = 'app';
  options = {
    'key': "rzp_key",
    //other fields if required 
  };


  constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) {
    this.rzp = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(this.options);
    this.rzpObservable = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    this.rzp.once('ready', (response) => {
      observer.next(response)
      })
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.rzpObservable.subscribe((response:any)=>{

    this.netbankingkeys=Object.keys(response.methods['netbanking']).map((key) => [{ name: response.methods['netbanking'][key], key: key }]);
  this.fetched=true;
  })

    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.netbankingkeys) }, 4000)

    setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.fetched) }, 4000)

  }

}
```

Comment: Why so many code to simply access `window`? It's easily accessible using just `window`.

Comment: @Sergey https://brianflove.com/2018/01/11/angular-window-provider/ so what are your opinion on this :)

Comment: Isn't every option should be done like it should solve 1000 and 1 problem that may arise (and mostly will not) since it only increases your code size and has bad affect on performance. You should solve the problem you have not any other 1000 you may encounter. Also, what is the reason to use `window` object with SSR? IMHO, SSR gives you a static page and your `window` access shouldn't be there.